# How to realize the lucene suggester with support contexts

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, lucene.net

Now only AnalyzingInfixSuggester support contexts. All other implementations, such as AnalyzingSuggester, FreeTextSuggester, FuzzySuggester not support contexts.
In my task I need to implementing suggester, which search only on terms which are exist in documents that have specific field with a specific value.
For example, only terms of field **description** of the documents in which the field **type** have value **TYPE_A**.

Now to solve this problem, I created different iterator for each **type**, 
like that:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> mapOfTerms...;        
    int maxDoc = indexReader.maxDoc();                 

    for (int i = 0; i < maxDoc; i++) {            

        Document doc = indexReader.document(i);
        String type = doc.get("type");

        List<String> list = mapOfTerms.get(type);
        //... add terms from doc to list            
    }

   //create custom InputIterator for each type list
   //create AnalyzingSuggester, AnalyzingInfixSuggester, FreeTextSuggester, FuzzySuggester for each InputIterator
```

For example, for three types "TYPE_A", "TYPE_B", TYPE_C" I make 12 suggesters.
How to solve this problem better?

Answer (score 0):

The question is about a context for suggester. My answer is about filtering the result as if the suggester would have been build only for a subset of the documents.
The lucene-folk calls this filter a context: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6464

Version 5.4 is the first solr version with supported filter on suggesters, but only for BlendedInfixSuggester and AnalyzingInfixSuggester:
[Make Lucene's AnalyzingInfixSuggester.lookup() method that takes a BooleanQuery filter parameter available in Solr](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7888)

So at time for all other suggesters you have to build one suggester for each possible filter e.g. by creating a extra field for each filter "field_filtername".

Without extra information I can not see how to solve this problem better.

Possible your context could be used as route for [Shard Splitting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud#ShardsandIndexingDatainSolrCloud-ShardSplitting) (and the separation of suggesters per context is already done by SolrCloud).

Possible you don't need a suggester at all and highlighting or facets could solve your original problem.

Comment: Thanks, that you mean: "So at time for all other suggesters you have to build one suggester for each possible filter e.g. by creating a extra field for each filter "field_filtername". ?

Comment: Now I made CustomInputIterator, CustomLuceneDictionary, CustomMultiFields for my case. Custom InputIterator contains only filtered terms. My approach requires that the field names contain the type name, eg field "title_typeA", "title_typeB"...